# @Html.EditorFor() Renders DropDownList Instead of CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor

I'm new from WebForms to MVC 3 and have an issue with the `@Html.EditorFor()` helper method.

I have a strongly typed view that represents data from a database, and one of the methods is of type `bool?`. I'd like this to appear as a checkbox, but instead it appears as a dropdownlist with the options "Not Set", "True" and "False".

What is the simplest way to covert this to a regular checkbox?

I understand that I could change the data type to a plain old `bool`, but this is a large EF entity I'm using and it seems a pain to have to recreate the entire class just for this. I also realize I'll lose the ability to track the "not set" state, but showing a simple checkbox is more important to me.

Comment: Do you have an item called "/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Boolean.*"?

Comment: No, I don't have an EditorTemplates folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the checkbox helper method instead, @Html.CheckBoxFor()

It's rendering a drop down list as a check box wouldn't be able to provide the value "not set".

Comment: I can seem to get `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` to work with `bool?` I guess it requires `bool`. I addressed the second part in my question.

Comment: if the value is NULL then you shouldn't display a checkbox. You'd need to wrap it round an if block and then something like (@html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Property.Value))

Comment: If the value is null, I still want to display a textbox. I can simply set it to unchecked.

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Property.Value, new { @checked = m.Property != null && m.Property})

Answer (score 6):

Basically, ASP.NET MVC has some default templates (you [can read that here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)).

If you wish, you could add your own EditorTemplate and ASP.NET MVC will use it instead of default. For this you should place a file 'Boolean.{your-view-engine-extension}' (ex.:  'Boolean.aspx') into either *~/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/* or *~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/* and override it with your own functionality.

Here is the default editor for Boolean, which can be enhanced by you:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
    private List<SelectListItem> TriStateValues {
        get {
            return new List<SelectListItem> {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Not Set", Value = String.Empty, Selected = !Value.HasValue },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value = "true", Selected = Value.HasValue && Value.Value },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value = "false", Selected = Value.HasValue && !Value.Value },
            };
        }
    }
    private bool? Value {
        get {
            if (ViewData.Model == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData.Model, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
</script>
<% if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("", TriStateValues, new { @class = "list-box tri-state" }) %>
<% } else { %>
    <%= Html.CheckBox("", Value ?? false, new { @class = "check-box" }) %>
<% } %>
```